# Can a Wizard select an alternative capstone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

More specifically, I'm building a Wizard and I'd like him to have the Perfect Body, Flawless Mind capstone (+8 Int).

I'm planning for him to be a diviner, specialized: Foresight, with the Pact Wizard (HH) archetype (that, as far I can tell, does not replace a wizard's capstone, since a wizard does not have one to begin with), and wonder if it'd still be legal to get the alternative capstone.

Does the natural 20 from Forewarned (Divination school) count as a capstone?

> At 20th level, anytime you roll initiative, assume the roll resulted in a natural 20.

If so, am I able to select the alternative capstone in its place (since it's not an archetype)?

If not, could I do it as an universalist?

Relevant [reference](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-Classes/wizard/#Alternative_Capstone_Ability):

> Alternative Capstone Ability
>
> When a character reaches the 20th level of a class, she gains a
> powerful class feature or ability, sometimes referred to as a
> capstone. When a character reaches 20th level in this class, the
> following new ability can be selected instead of the standard 20th
> level class ability which would normally be gained. In some cases, a
> capstone specifies what ability it replaces. A character can’t select
> an alternative capstone if she has previously traded away her class
> capstone via an archetype. Clerics and wizards can receive a capstone
> at 20th level, despite not having one to begin with.

Comment: where is your pact wizard published? HH is not an abbreviation I know. Please link to the relevant class of your archetype if possible or tell who is the publisher of the product it is from if it isn't paizo.

Comment: Pact Wizard is an archetype that Paizo has published twice, in the Haunted Heroes Handbook (HH, per d20pfsrd) Player Companion and Familiar Folio (FF per d20pfsrd) Player Companion. [Haunted Heroes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/pact-wizard-wizard-archetype/) (2016) is the more recent publication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can*

As a Wizard, you lose nothing to gain an Alternative Capstone. Specifically, from the rules you linked:

> Clerics and **wizards can receive a capstone at 20th level, despite not having one to begin with.**

You can select one applicable Alternative Capstone. There is a better list on the [Archives of Nethys Wizard](https://www.aonprd.com/ClassDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wizard) page, which includes your desired one.

---

*I have not played in a game with Alternative Capstones allowed. I would check with your GM that they're accessible and see if they want you to exchange a class feature despite the text; giving Wizards and Clerics *more* for free could significantly affect their game balance, especially at the highest level of play.

Comment: Never thought to check Nethys' wizard page, this issue seems clearer there. Thank you!